# Brew stops working after terminal session is closed

Tags: macos, installation, terminal, homebrew, macos-monterey

I have installed Brew in MACOS Monterey with the following commands.
`mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew`

`eval "$(homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`

`brew update --force --quiet`

`chmod -R go-w "$(brew --prefix)/share/zsh"`

I have tested it after the install, and it works, however closing the terminal session and opening it again causes terminal to say that the command `brew` is not found after running it. I can still see the `homebrew` directory, so Im guessing its in the wrong place for terminal to run it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I was able to fix the issue by adding the PATH to the `.bash_profile` file.

Answer (score 0):

The only supported method to install brew is found on [brew.sh](https://brew.sh):

- `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

Comment: Actually, in the docs page, there **is** an alternate way to install brew:[link](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation)

Comment: That is an unsupported method.  Instructions for a supported install of Homebrew are on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

For me works adding:

`eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`

to `~/.zshrc`